# How do I find the angle between the center of the earth and two latitude-longitude coordinates

Tags: gis, distance, latitude-longitude, angle

I've got two LatLon (latitude-longitude) objects which represent two locations on the surface of the globe. I want to find the angle (in radians) between the center of the earth and these two LatLon objects.

I'm going to use this angle and the radius of the earth to calculate the arc length between the two locations (I figure this will give better precision than using simple Pythagoras, and be faster than computing the great circle distance).

I already have code to give me the Pythagorean distance and the great circle distance.

Comment: How accurate does it need to be, and over what distances?  If we're talking about points thousands of miles apart, you may incur significant errors (on the order of miles) by assuming a simplified model like a spherical Earth.

Comment: If you want arclength you have to use great circles.  Otherwise you will get euclidean distance which isn't accurate on the surface of a sphere.  Check out this wikipedia article for some insight: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance.  By the way, if you ask this over at gis.stackexhange.com you might get more answers.

Comment: @SRM, correct link: http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, worst case the Pythagorean distance is out by about 25,000 kilometers (15,000 miles). Great circle is ~10x slower but much more accurate. I'm basically looking for a balance between the speed and accuracy of these two methods :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using something like this - [how to calculate the angle between two vectors](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/index.htm)

Comment: So I convert the LatLons to cartesian coordinates, normalize them, take the dot product, then compute the inverse cosine? Is there an easier way?

Comment: This results in euclidean distance which is wildly inaccurate on the surface of a sphere.

Comment: @wpearse yes, arc-length on the surface of the earth is NOT a trivial calculation.

Comment: I ended up using this solution. Not perfect, but it turned out to be a have an acceptable speed-precision balance...

Answer (score -2):

I thought this at first (after some calc on paper) is this Pythagorean thing?
`angle_between_radian = sqrt(deltaLA^2 + deltaLO^2)*PI /180`
edit: `delta = delta>180?360-delta:delta`
We working on sphere then above must wrong ^^. 
But this link may help:[Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Comment: Not even close.  Imagine two points straddling the north pole, 1 inch apart, but differing by 180 degrees of longitude...

Comment: This just an idea, delta we neel should not be larger than 180 then you can make modify like 360- delta if delta > 180 ...